# how to quickly locate which sheets/dashboards contain a field?

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a data dictionary and I am supposed to track the location of any used field in a workbook. For example (superstore sample data), I need to specify which sheets/dashboards have the **[sub-category]** field.

My dataset has hundreds of measures/dimensions/calc fields, so it's incredibly time exhaustive to click into every single sheet/dashboard just to see if a field exists in there, so is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: If you are in an environment with a Tableau Server that has the Data Management Add-on installed, you can use Tableau’s Data Catalog to quickly see which fields are used in which views.

Comment: Sadly, my company does not have that add-on installed

Comment: @AlexBlakemore is there anything I could do within tableau prep to assist with this?

Comment: @AlexBlakemore I did try opening up the workbook via notepad to view the XML code. Is there a quick reference in there that would indicate the sheet name that field is on?

Answer (score 0):

One robust, but not free, approach is to use Tableau's Data Catalog which is part of the Tableau Server Data Management Add-On

Another option is to build your own cross reference - You could start with Chris Gerrard's ruby libraries described in the article http://tableaufriction.blogspot.com/2018/09/documenting-dashboards-and-their.html